# Mandrill Curl Request Returning Invalid Key Error

Tags: json, api, post, curl, mandrill

I am trying to send an email via the Mandrill API, but it is throwing an error with the key(s) I provide. Below is the `text.json` file I am including in my curl request.

```
{
'key' : 'MyActualKey',
'message': {
    'html': '<p>Example HTML content</p>',
    'text': 'Example text content',
    'subject': 'example subject',
    'from_email': 'from@example.com',
    'from_name': 'Test',
    'to': [
        {
            'email': 'to@example.com',
            'name': 'Eric Clapton',
            'type': 'to'
        }
    ],
    'headers': {
        'Reply-To': 'reply@example.com'
    },
    'merge': True,
    'tags': [
        'Mandrill Test'
    ]
 },
'ip_pool': 'Main Pool'
}
```

Then I execute this curl command:

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @test.json https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json -v`

Resulting in this output with the error shown on the last line:

```
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7fd922803a00
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7fd922803a00) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to mandrillapp.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 54.221.22.61...
* Connected to mandrillapp.com (54.221.22.61) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
* Server certificate: mandrillapp.com
* Server certificate: Thawte SSL CA
* Server certificate: thawte Primary Root CA
* Server certificate: Thawte Premium Server CA
> POST /api/1.0/messages/send.json HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: mandrillapp.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 501
>
* upload completely sent off: 501 out of 501 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
* Server nginx/1.6.0 is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.6.0
< Date: Sat, 14 Jun 2014 23:46:44 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false
<
* Connection #0 to host mandrillapp.com left intact
{"status":"error","code":-1,"name":"ValidationError","message":"You must specify a key value"}
```

Notice how the last line says 'specify a key value' - again, this is the exact key from the Mandrill control panel. I even generated a couple more and they all failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change it into a valid json and see if that helps:

1. Change all single quotes into double quotes
2. Change the value of "merge" from "True" to lower case "true".

Comment: Had a similar issue. it didn't like the type of single quote (vs apostrophe I guess?) so change ` to '